# Unable to append item in a list after slicing it python

Tags: python, list, append, slice

```
list = [54, 44, 27, 79, 91, 41]

num_4 = list[4]
def fun_2():
    y = list[:2]
    z = y.append(num_4)
    print(z)
fun_2()
```

code above is giving me None output,
objective- first slice a list then append a integer to it.

Comment: As a side note - don't use `list` as name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `z` does not contain the list but the `y` does.

`List` is mutable in python, which means,

```
y = list[:2]
z = y.append(num_4)
```

the above code will add `num_4` to `y` and `append()` function returns `none` hence `z` will contain `none`.

So print `y` not `z`